# Remove from the mui timepicker the hh:mm, which appears when focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

Remove from the mui timepicker the hh:mm, which appears when focused, this text is positioned in the value property of the textfield, only when it is focused:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol3OA.png)

Code of component, custom timepicker

```
import React, { forwardRef, useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns'
import enLocale from 'date-fns/locale/en-US'
import esLocale from 'date-fns/locale/es'
import { Tooltip } from '@chilecompra/react-kit/components'
import useTimePickerBase from './TimePicker.hook'
import {
  BottomMessage,
  Error,
  Info,
  Label,
  Required,
  Root,
  Skeleton,
  TimePickerBase,
  TimePickerProvider,
  TooltipIcon,
  Wrapper
} from './TimePicker.styles'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import theme from '../../config/styles/theme'

export const useTimePicker = useTimePickerBase

const LOCALE_DICTIONARY = {
  en: enLocale,
  es: esLocale
}

export const TimePicker = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {
    ampm,
    disabled,
    disableFuture,
    disablePast,
    disableToolbar,
    error,
    format,
    info,
    label,
    loading,
    locale,
    margin,
    maxTime,
    minTime,
    padding,
    placeholder,
    required,
    size,
    success,
    tooltip,
    value,
    width,
    onChange,
    ...restProps
  } = props

  const openRef = useRef(false)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleBlur = useCallback(
    event => {
      if (restProps?.onBlur && typeof restProps?.onBlur === 'function') {
        restProps?.onBlur(event)
      }

      if (openRef.current) {
        return
      }

      onChange(value)
    },
    [onChange, restProps, value]
  )
  const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
    openRef.current = false
    setOpen(false)
  }, [])
  const handleOpen = useCallback(() => {
    openRef.current = true
    setOpen(true)
  }, [])
  const handleKeyDown = useCallback(e => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }, [])

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TimePickerProvider adapterLocale={LOCALE_DICTIONARY[locale]} dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <Root margin={margin} padding={padding} ref={ref} width={width}>
          {label && (
            <Label size={size}>
              {label}
              {required && <Required size={size} />}
              {tooltip && (
                <Tooltip content={tooltip}>
                  <TooltipIcon focusable tanIndex="0" size={size} />
                </Tooltip>
              )}
            </Label>
          )}
          <Wrapper>
            {loading && <Skeleton size={size} variant="rectangular" />}
            {!loading && (
              <TimePickerBase
                ampm={ampm}
                autoFocus
                closeOnSelect
                disabled={disabled}
                disableFuture={disableFuture}
                disablePast={disablePast}
                disableToolbar={disableToolbar}
                format={format}
                label=""
                open={open}
                maxTime={maxTime}
                minTime={minTime}
                slotProps={{
                  textField: {
                    error: Boolean(error),
                    placeholder: placeholder,
                    onBlur: handleBlur,
                    onClick: handleOpen,
                    onKeyDown: handleKeyDown
                  }
                }}
                size={size}
                success={success}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                onClose={handleClose}
                onOpen={handleOpen}
              />
            )}
          </Wrapper>
          <BottomMessage size={size}>
            {!error && <Info>{info}</Info>}
            {error && !loading && <Error>{error}</Error>}
          </BottomMessage>
        </Root>
      </TimePickerProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
})

TimePicker.defaultProps = {
  ampm: false,
  disabled: false,
  disableFuture: false,
  disablePast: false,
  disableToolbar: false,
  error: '',
  format: 'HH:mm',
  info: '',
  label: '',
  loading: false,
  locale: 'es',
  margin: 0,
  maxTime: undefined,
  minTime: undefined,
  padding: 0,
  placeholder: '',
  required: false,
  size: 'medium',
  success: false,
  tooltip: '',
  value: null,
  width: '100%'
}

TimePicker.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Am or PM.
   */
  ampm: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Disabled.
   */
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Disable future.
   */
  disableFuture: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Disable past.
   */
  disablePast: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Disable toolbar.
   */
  disableToolbar: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Error.
   */
  error: PropTypes.string,
  /**
   * Format.
   */
  format: PropTypes.string,
  /**
   * Info.
   */
  info: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.string]),
  /**
   * Label.
   */
  label: PropTypes.string,
  /**
   * Loading.
   */
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Locale.
   */
  locale: PropTypes.oneOf(['en', 'es']),
  /**
   * Margin.
   */
  margin: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string]),
  /**
   * Max date.
   */
  maxTime: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date),
  /**
   * Min date.
   */
  minTime: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date),
  /**
   * Padding.
   */
  padding: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string]),
  /**
   * Placeholder.
   */
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  /**
   * Required.
   */
  required: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Size.
   */
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(['large', 'medium', 'small']),
  /**
   * success.
   */
  success: PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * Tooltip.
   */
  tooltip: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.string]),
  /**
   * Value.
   */
  value: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date).isRequired,
  /**
   * Width.
   */
  width: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
  /**
   * On change.
   */
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default TimePicker
```

I need to remove the hh:mm text that is added when the component is focused.

do something like this:

```
onFucus={() => setValue('')}
```

My code of style-component:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'
import { styled } from '@mui/material'
import { LocalizationProvider as LocalizationProviderBase, TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { Help as HelpIcon } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { Skeleton as BaseSkeleton } from '@chilecompra/react-kit/components'

export const Root = styled('div')`
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.typography.fontFamily};
  margin: ${props => props.margin};
  padding: ${props => props.padding};
  width: ${props => props.width};
`

export const Label = styled(({ size, ...props }) => <label {...props} />)`
  color: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[50]};
  font-size: ${props => {
    if (props.size === 'large') {
      return '14px'
    }

    return '12px'
  }};
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  line-height: ${props => {
    if (props.size === 'small') {
      return '14px'
    }

    return '16px'
  }};
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`

export const Required = styled(({ size, ...props }) => <span {...props}>*</span>)`
  color: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[50]};
  font-size: ${props => {
    if (props.size === 'large') {
      return '1.1rem'
    }

    return '1rem'
  }};
  margin: 0 0 0 4px;
`

export const TooltipIcon = styled(forwardRef(({ size, ...props }, ref) => <HelpIcon {...props} ref={ref} />))`
  &.MuiSvgIcon-root {
    fill: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[50]};
    font-size: ${props => {
      if (props.size === 'large') {
        return '1rem'
      }

      return '0.8rem'
    }};
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
  }

  &.MuiSvgIcon-root:focus {
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[95]};
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: none;
  }
`

export const Skeleton = styled(({ size, ...props }) => <BaseSkeleton {...props} />)`
  &.MuiSkeleton-root {
    height: ${props => {
      if (props.size === 'large') {
        return '46px'
      }
      if (props.size === 'small') {
        return '26px'
      }
      return '36px'
    }};
  }
`

export const Wrapper = styled('div')`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
`

export const TimePickerProvider = styled(LocalizationProviderBase)``

export const BottomMessage = styled(({ size, ...props }) => <div {...props} />)`
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.typography.fontFamily};
  font-size: ${props => {
    if (props.size === 'large') {
      return '14px'
    }

    if (props.size === 'small') {
      return '11px'
    }

    return '12px'
  }};
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 3px 0 0;
  min-height: 20px;
`

export const Info = styled('section')`
  color: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[50]};
`

export const Error = styled('section')`
  color: ${props => props.theme.palette.red[50]};
`

export const TimePickerBase = styled(
  forwardRef(({ size, success, textAlign, ...props }, ref) => <TimePicker {...props} ref={ref} />)
)`
  &.MuiFormControl-root {
    border: 0;
    height: ${props => {
      if (props.size === 'large') {
        return 'calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 17.2px)'
      }

      if (props.size === 'small') {
        return 'calc(1.5em + 0.95rem)'
      }

      return 'calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 10.2px)'
    }};
    width: 100%;
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.palette.brand.white};
    border: 1px solid ${props => (props.success ? props.theme.palette.green[50] : props.theme.palette.gray[85])};
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[20]};
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    font-size: ${props => {
      if (props.size === 'large') {
        return '16px'
      }

      if (props.size === 'small') {
        return '12px'
      }

      return '14px'
    }};
    height: ${props => {
      if (props.size === 'large') {
        return 'calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 14px)'
      }

      if (props.size === 'small') {
        return 'calc(1.5em + 0.75rem)'
      }

      return 'calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 7px)'
    }};
    line-height: ${props => {
      if (props.size === 'small') {
        return '14px'
      }

      return '16px'
    }};
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    width: calc(100% - 0.4rem);
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    text-align: ${props => props.textAlign};
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;

    &::placeholder {
      color: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[75]};
      font-family: ${props => props.theme.typography.fontFamily};
      font-size: ${props => {
        if (props.size === 'large') {
          return '16px'
        }

        if (props.size === 'small') {
          return '12px'
        }

        return '14px'
      }};
      line-height: ${props => {
        if (props.size === 'small') {
          return '14px'
        }

        return '16px'
      }};
      opacity: 1;
      transition: none;
    }
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-focused {
    border: 1px solid ${props => (props.success ? props.theme.palette.green[50] : props.theme.palette.blue[50])};
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem
      ${props => (props.success ? props.theme.palette.green[50.4] : props.theme.palette.blue[50.25])};
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled {
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[95]};
    border: 1px solid ${props => (props.success ? props.theme.palette.green[50] : props.theme.palette.gray[85])};
    color: ${props => props.theme.palette.brand.disableFont};
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled input {
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-error {
    border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.palette.red[50]};
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-error.Mui-focused {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem ${props => props.theme.palette.red[50.5]};
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root .MuiButtonBase-root:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root .MuiTouchRipple-root {
    display: none;
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root .MuiInputAdornment-root {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root .MuiInputAdornment-root .MuiButtonBase-root {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    top: initial;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .MuiInputBase-root .MuiInputAdornment-root .MuiButtonBase-root .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    fill: ${props => props.theme.palette.gray[50]};
    font-size: ${props => {
      if (props.size === 'large') {
        return '26px'
      }

      if (props.size === 'small') {
        return '20px'
      }

      return '24px'
    }};
  }

  fieldset {
    border: 0;
  }
`
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.